# Installing win32com for python 3.8.8

Tags: python, win32com

I have tried installing win32com on python version 3.8.8 using several methods finally settling on

```
!python -m pip install pypiwin32
```

However I am getting this error.

```
Collecting pypiwin32
  Downloading pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
  Downloading pypiwin32-219.zip (4.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 4.8 MB 3.2 MB/s eta 0:00:01
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/conda/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-rxlumrt5/pypiwin32_d674fe4e172b4a5ab12b6b8f2aeb2d90/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-rxlumrt5/pypiwin32_d674fe4e172b4a5ab12b6b8f2aeb2d90/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-eb1keprl
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-rxlumrt5/pypiwin32_d674fe4e172b4a5ab12b6b8f2aeb2d90/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-rxlumrt5/pypiwin32_d674fe4e172b4a5ab12b6b8f2aeb2d90/setup.py", line 121
        print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
              ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Building pywin32", pywin32_version)?
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/ca/5c086c18de8f70222787b3e824e755b68d99272531522e77bb381d4f60c8/pypiwin32-219.zip#sha256=06d478295c89dbdd4187e1ac099bb8eab93c29e298bded4e2fbc77009287fa44 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pypiwin32/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223
```

Requesting assistance.

Thanks and Regards,

Yadhunandan

Answer (score 0):

Last time I used win32com I installed the package pywin32, not pypiwin32. I am not sure how well pypiwin32 is maintained, as there is no project description on pypi and it only has 3 Releases, the last being in 2018 (https://pypi.org/project/pypiwin32/).

So maybe try this one:
https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/

Comment: I actually tried installing pywin32 initially. However changed it to pypiwin32 based on an error and answers from a different post. However will try this with -m. Thanks.